# Get info of applied image manipulation

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, gm

I am using [gm for node](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm). I would like know the equivalent Javascript of the ImageMagick CLI command:

`convert /path/to/source.png -format "%@" info:-`

This will output the trim data, resulting in something like:

`2672x3579+1115+725`

I initially assumed the gm equivalent would be:

```
gm('/path/to/source.png').identify('%@', (err, result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

But this just returns the source file size **without** trimming whitespace.

`5000x5000+0+0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
gm('/path/to/source.png')
  .in('-format', '%@')
  .write('info:-', (err, result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

The writing to `info:-` was the aha moment.

Comment: Well done and +1 for sharing. I have also fallen foul of `gm` requiring that extra dash at the end!

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
gm convert a.png -format "%@" info:-
```

Or this way:

```
gm convert a.png -trim -format "%w %h" info:-
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't speak JS - I was hoping that someone else might be able to help out with the other half of the answer if I provided the half I know.